# Linearlayout with horizontal children with predefined width

Tags: android, material-design, android-linearlayout, margin, android-button

I've got a simple layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    >

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/BrightYellowCrayola"
        android:insetLeft="0dp"
        android:insetTop="0dp"
        android:insetRight="0dp"
        android:insetBottom="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        app:icon="@drawable/outline_two_wheeler_24"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        app:iconPadding="0dp"
        app:iconSize="24dp"
        app:iconTint="@null"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Button.Circle" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"

        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/BrightYellowCrayola"
        android:insetLeft="0dp"
        android:insetTop="0dp"
        android:insetRight="0dp"
        android:insetBottom="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        app:icon="@drawable/outline_two_wheeler_24"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        app:iconPadding="0dp"
        app:iconSize="24dp"
        app:iconTint="@null"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Button.Circle" />


    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/BrightYellowCrayola"
        android:insetLeft="0dp"
        android:insetTop="0dp"
        android:insetRight="0dp"
        android:insetBottom="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        app:icon="@drawable/outline_two_wheeler_24"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        app:iconPadding="0dp"
        app:iconSize="24dp"
        app:iconTint="@null"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Button.Circle" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/BrightYellowCrayola"
        android:insetLeft="0dp"
        android:insetTop="0dp"
        android:insetRight="0dp"
        android:insetBottom="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        app:icon="@drawable/outline_two_wheeler_24"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        app:iconPadding="0dp"
        app:iconSize="24dp"
        app:iconTint="@null"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Button.Circle" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Which looks lke this:

[image: current output]

The issue, as seen above is that the predefined button width of "50dp" won't be used as the `layout_weight` attribute, for some reason, always corrects the size so that the width fits completely in the linearlayout. What I want, is the NOT the width is corrected but rather the margin between the 4 buttons, with the width staying the same.

So it should look more like this:

[image: expected result]

Can this be solved using `layout_weight`attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    >


    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/BrightYellowCrayola"
        android:insetLeft="0dp"
        android:insetTop="0dp"
        android:insetRight="0dp"
        android:insetBottom="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        app:icon="@drawable/outline_two_wheeler_24"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        app:iconPadding="0dp"
        app:iconSize="24dp"
        app:iconTint="@null"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Button.Circle" />


    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />



    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/BrightYellowCrayola"
        android:insetLeft="0dp"
        android:insetTop="0dp"
        android:insetRight="0dp"
        android:insetBottom="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        app:icon="@drawable/outline_two_wheeler_24"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        app:iconPadding="0dp"
        app:iconSize="24dp"
        app:iconTint="@null"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Button.Circle" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />



    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/BrightYellowCrayola"
        android:insetLeft="0dp"
        android:insetTop="0dp"
        android:insetRight="0dp"
        android:insetBottom="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        app:icon="@drawable/outline_two_wheeler_24"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        app:iconPadding="0dp"
        app:iconSize="24dp"
        app:iconTint="@null"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Button.Circle" />


    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/BrightYellowCrayola"
        android:insetLeft="0dp"
        android:insetTop="0dp"
        android:insetRight="0dp"
        android:insetBottom="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        app:icon="@drawable/outline_two_wheeler_24"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        app:iconPadding="0dp"
        app:iconSize="24dp"
        app:iconTint="@null"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Button.Circle" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Using space is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

`layout_weight` will not solve your problem. Put a `layout_marginRight` and `layout_marginLeft` for your `com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton` of say `20dp` not for your `<LinearLayout />`